# Auto update doesn't work : MAC os Target .pkg

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-updater

Previously we were using **.dmg** target and published on the **S3 bucket**, So on S3 and electron app it creates **latest-mac.yml** and **app-update.yml** files automatically, and for the next version app automatically update.

But Right now we are using target as **.pkg** . The auto-updater is now stopped. **latest-mac.yml** and **app-update.yml** are not creating for **.pkg** target. But build uploaded to s3 successfully.

package.json

```
"package-ci": "yarn postinstall && yarn build && electron-builder --publish always",
.....
"mac": {
      "entitlements": "build/entitlements.mac.inherit.plist",
      "entitlementsInherit": "build/entitlements.mac.inherit.plist",
      "icon": "./resources/icon.png",
      "target": [
        "pkg"
      ]
    },
    ........
     "publish": {
      "provider": "s3",
      "bucket": "build",
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.electron.build/auto-update.html
Unfortunately the only listed targets supported are dmg, appimage, and nsis